# Errors in pom.xml file

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

[image: This is the error page in pom.xml]

Ive just started with spring tool suite and created my first project 
   'springeg'. I have tried updating maven but errors remained same.. what should 
    i do?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the Java 1.8 might be it can be the reason behind this and please try to use this configuration-

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>



<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Please remove the existing spring boot starter dependency of the old version and also remove the older java version dependency there will be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

wipe the local Maven repository (~/.m2/repository) and hit the "Maven -> Update Project..." in STS again.

Answer (score 0):

For pom.xml, It is gving error for invalid LOC header. It seems the dependency you are adding, there is some problem with that.

The jar might be corrupt.